# Custom number of faces

Tags: transforms

Hello I have a cylinder with 32 inner faces. I need to make 42 inner faces with the same width of faces. Subdivide doesn't help me bcs when i divide all faces to half i will make 62 faces. And when i divide some of faces, all faces will not have the same width.

[image: cylinder with 32 faces]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be much, much easier to reconstruct the cylinder from scratch, this time before confirming, set 42 subdivisions...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a more complex shape than a cylinder that is still a solid of revolution, using the revolution modifier can be really useful.
Instead of modeling the complete object, just create its profile and add a `Screw` modifier.

Using this modifier will allow you to change the number of faces with the `Steps` parameter, without rebuilding your object from scratch.

Simple example with a bent profile
[image: Screw modifier example]